# How to get trends about requests/answered counts?

Tags: discussion, statistics, trends

I found some external sites that publish some statistics like :

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/
- http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

These are quite old, and I didn’t find simple trends with daily questions count and answers count.
Whatever is the technology used to store requests in stackoverflow, I guess the information is available.

Is it available in some way ? through API ?

Comment: The Alexa information appears to be current.  Did you really mean that they don't provide the *kind* of information you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59302/questions-and-answers-per-month) will show you how many questions and answers has been posted per month since the creation of StackOverflow. You cane even run it on every sites of the StackExchange network.

FYI, 191,998 questions has been asked in December 2013, with a total of 283,532 answers on SO only.